# How to clear session when leave controller in zend framework?

Tags: session, zend-framework, controller

Assume that I'm in indexAction of IndexController. I stored some data in session. Now I want to clear all session when I move to another controller, let's say that ExampleController. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to clear **all** Session namespaces:

```
Zend_Session::destroy();
```

To clear one specific nameSpace:

```
 Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('default');
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe with

```
$bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
$cache = $bootstrap->getResource('cache');
$cache->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL);
```